# List of Buttons one below other inside JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane, gridbaglayout

I want to make list of JButtons (with fixed dimensions, one beneath another) inside JScrollPane, using Swing. My idea was to make JPanel with GridBagLayout and add buttons in their suiting rows, and then create JScrollPane with that JPanel. That looks fine when number of buttons is large, but when the number of buttons is 2 or 3, I can't manage to align buttons one right below the other.
Also later I will add option to add new button (thus the + sign).

1. [Works fine with 10 buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liGdc.png)
2. [I get this empty space between button 0 and button 1 when it's just 2 buttons (this is the problem)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EdK2.png)

3. The code (creates upper east panel)

```java
    private JPanel createLayerPanel() {
        JPanel layerPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        // Label ------------------------------------------------
        JLabel layersLabel = new JLabel("Buttons");
        layersLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        layersLabel.setFont(DEFAULT_FONT);
        //layersLabel.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.red, 3));
        layersLabel.setBackground(new Color(0x22222));
        layersLabel.setForeground(new Color(0xFFFFFF));

        layersLabel.setOpaque(true);
        c.gridx = c.gridy = 0;
        c.ipadx = 180;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        layerPanel.add(layersLabel, c);

        // Button ------------------------------------------------
        JButton newLayerBtn = new JButton("+");
        newLayerBtn.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 18));
        newLayerBtn.setBackground(new Color(0x222222));
        newLayerBtn.setForeground(Color.white);
        newLayerBtn.setFocusable(false);
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.ipadx = 0;
        c.weightx = 0;
        layerPanel.add(newLayerBtn, c);

        // ScrollPane ------------------------------------------------
        //------------------------------------------------------------
        //------------------------------------------------------------

        JPanel layerListPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        layerListPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.ipady = 40;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;

        for (gbc.gridy = 0; gbc.gridy < 10; gbc.gridy++) {
            JButton btn = new JButton("Button " + gbc.gridy);
            layerListPanel.add(btn, gbc);
        }
        JScrollPane js = new JScrollPane(layerListPanel);
        js.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

        // ...
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        layerPanel.add(js, c);
        return layerPanel;

    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the size of the panel, containing the buttons, depends on the other components in your GUI - which you chose not to reveal. Maybe if you posted the code of your entire GUI, it would reveal why you are getting the behavior you describe. Alternatively, did you try `BoxLayout` or single column `GridLayout` instead of `GridBagLayout`?

Comment: @Abra I really appreciate your answer, but when I use my "technique" independently in frame it again doesn't do what I want it to do. I don't see how GridLayout can solve my problem, but I will definitely try with BoxLayout  (which I'm less familiar with).

Comment: I recommend [How to Use Various Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/layoutlist.html)

Comment: *"when I use my "technique" independently in frame"* Post a [mre] of that, rather than uncompilable code snippets from the main app.

Answer (score 1):

Do you absolutely need a GridBagLayout?
I just made a demo using a simple Box.
And please have a look at [How to write an SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class YY extends JFrame {
  static String[] args;

  public YY() {
    setSize(160, 200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    int icnt= args.length==0 ? 5 : Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    Box box= Box.createVerticalBox();
    for (int i=1; i<=icnt; i++) {
      JButton btn= new JButton("Button "+i);
      btn.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 30));
      box.add(btn);
    }
    JScrollPane scroll= new JScrollPane(box);
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 100));
    add(scroll);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String... args) {
    YY.args= args;
    EventQueue.invokeLater(YY::new);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I absolutely don't need GridBagLayout, but intuitively I thought that was the kind of layout I needed here. Using Box solves my problem in case I need 2-3 buttons, but when I use more buttons than it can fit inside ScrollPane, their height shinks to fit the capacity, which I want to avoid. I need buttons to be fixed size. setMinimumSize() doesn't seem to work here, I don't understand why.
I'm sorry for not being clear in my question, this is my first question here, I will definitely try to engage more in future.

Comment: Set **all** the sizes of a button, i.e. minimum, maximum and preferred - and the buttons will not shrink any more.

Comment: The preferred/minimum/maximum size of a JButton is the same. @VasiliS. the buttons should not shrink in size. Post your [mre] using a BoxLayout that demonstrates this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The below code initially displays a `JFrame` that contains a single `JButton` that displays the text **Add**. Each time you click the button a new `JButton` appears above it. The text on each newly created button is a three digit number with leading zeros that is incremented each time the **Add** button is clicked. And whenever a new button is added, the `JFrame` increases in height in order to display the newly added button.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class GridBttn implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private int  counter;
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JPanel  gridPanel;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        addButtonToGridPanel();
    }

    private void addButtonToGridPanel() {
        JButton button = new JButton(String.format("%03d", counter++));
        gridPanel.add(button);
        frame.pack();
    }

    private JButton createButton(String text) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        return button;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.add(createButton("Add"));
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createGridPanel() {
        gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        return gridPanel;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Grid");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createGridPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new GridBttn());
    }
}
```

Note the parameters to `GridLayout` constructor. Zero rows and one column. This means that whenever a `Component` is added to the `JPanel` it will be placed directly beneath the last `Component` added. In other words all the components added will appear in a single column. Also note that I call method `pack()` (of class `JFrame`) after adding a new button. This causes the `JFrame` to recalculate its size in order to display all the buttons.

### EDIT

Due to OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602068/list-of-buttons-one-below-other-inside-jscrollpane/62603853#comment110710789_62603853) slightly modified above code so as to be more suitable to his requirements.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class GridBttn implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private int  counter;
    private JFrame  frame;
    private JPanel  gridPanel;
    private JPanel  gridPanel2;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        showGui();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        addButtonToGridPanel();
    }

    private void addButtonToGridPanel() {
        JButton button = new JButton(String.format("%03d", counter++));
        gridPanel2.add(button);
        frame.pack();
    }

    private JButton createButton(String text) {
        JButton button = new JButton(text);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        return button;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonsPanel.add(createButton("Add"));
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        gridPanel = new JPanel();
        gridPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        return gridPanel;
    }

    private JScrollPane createScrollPane() {
        gridPanel2 = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(gridPanel2, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
        gridPanel2.setLayout(layout);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(gridPanel2,
                                                 ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                                                 ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(70, 0));
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Grid");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createMainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createScrollPane(), BorderLayout.LINE_END);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new GridBttn());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great @Abra and thank you, but it's not quite what I meant. I need to add buttons, one by one, one right below the other, all inside the east panel of the frame. It needs to be scrollable, so I need to use JScrollPane. Also, buttons need to have fixed size. If there is any space left between last button and bottom edge of the panel, it needs to be shown like that. Something like what you see when you open Wifi icon in Windows taskbar. I hope i'm more being more clear now. Do you think BoxLayout can help me with this somehow?